# WIQL and other languages

Tags: javascript, soap, tfs, sdk, wiql

Is WIQL specific to the TFS SDK or can it be used in other languages?

For example if I have built a client using TFS SDK that gets info about projects on the tfs, is it possible to somehow reuse the WIQL if I want to build a javascript client that does the same thing? Or is WIQL only used internally by the tfs sdk to create the proper soap request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your WIQL is processed on the TFS App Tier so, yes, you could conceivably write a Javascript client that sent WIQL queries to the server (in the context of a properly formed SOAP call). I wouldn't recommend it, however. The SOAP API for work item tracking isn't conducive to that approach.

Comment: Can you show me an example on how to create the soap request to do this? Initially I was thinking of generating javascript code using wsdl2js (apache cxf) and call the service from there? Would this be a better approach?